# JQuery DatePicker misalignment issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I've used JQuery Datepicker many times before without issue, but now I'm getting a misalignment issue that's got me stumped. The days are floating left, and the dates are floating right.

[image: DatePicker misalignment]

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="w100h005">
<input id="expdate" class="datepicker" placeholder="Expiry Date"></input>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.w100h005{display:block;width:100%;height:5vh;float:left;margin:1% 0 0 0;}
```

LINKS:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

JQuery initialisation:

```
$(function(){$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});});
$('.datepicker').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Comment: inspect the date and days element and see what css is overwriting the default style

Comment: @jabbar the only thing I'm specifying in css is the width of the text input with class datepicker.

Comment: can you provide online url to see and inspect the issue?

Comment: @jabbar I can't as it is on an internal intranet and you will need to have vpn access. I've edited the question to show my code, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i checked your code and it has no problem:

```js
$(function(){$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});});
$('.datepicker').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

```css
div.w100h005{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:5vh;
  float:left;
  margin:1% 0 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div class="w100h005">
<input id="expdate" class="datepicker" placeholder="Expiry Date">
</div>
```

BTW there is two way you can choose:
1- find the css that cause this issue: inspect it and see what is overwritten 
2- write some extra css and overwrite to fix the problem